# How can I get the total number of elements between two iterators?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, containers, iterator-traits

I had written a function to test that all the elements in a container were unique.

```
template<class InputIt>
bool all_elements_unique(InputIt first, InputIt last){
  std::set<typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type> s(first,last);
  return s.size() == std::distance(first,last);
}
```

It works.  However, the `size_t` returned from `size()` and the `difference_type` returned from `distance()`, are not of the same sign.

```
 warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions [-Wsign-compare]
```

[std::distance](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) may return negative numbers based on the direction of the iterators.

If that's the case, how could I reliably get the total number of elements between two iterators, when the amount of elements exceeds the signed maximum?  I was looking for something like [std::size](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/size), but it takes an entire container.

Comment: *"when the amount of elements exceeds the signed maximum?"* I have yet to see that happen in the real world. On 64 bit systems, it won't.

Comment: Also, Input Iterator is not strong enough here, incrementing one invalidates all copies. You need at least forward iterator.

Comment: And as distance counts elements, not bytes. It also wont happen on a 32 bit system.

Comment: @MikeMB: some code makes use of `vector<char>` (or even the notorious `vector<bool>`).

Comment: @MikeMB `vector<bool>::iterator` says hi :)

Comment: @MikeMB One could technically have a `vector<char>` that eats more than half of total RAM. But yeah, when was the last time you had this? (The `vector<bool>` could even "overflow" `size_t`! What a scary world we live in.)

Comment: So I should just static_cast what I get back from std::distance, and move on?

Comment: @TrevorHickey Unless you know to have that special requirement, I would say yes.

Comment: Btw, here is what some of the committee members think about unsigned integers: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Interactive-Panel-Ask-Us-Anything 9:50, 42:40, 1:02:50  They are more reputable than I am I guess.

Comment: `static_cast<>` and move on sounds reasonable, or you loop doing and counting set insertions.  If you wanted to get "fancy", you could create a helper wrapper type that counts the number of times a contained/managed iterator is incremented, so the `set` constructor incidentally calculates the distance.  (You'd need to wrap the `last` iterator too when providing it, so they're of the same type, but there'd be no iterations using the extra counter).

Comment: Actually, if `sizeof(T) == 1`, you can conclude that not all elements are unique if the original size is greater than `256`, so you can check for that before calling the above function if you are super paranoid.

Comment: @T.C.: And how many unique chars and bools are there? I hope no one tries to put 2^31 elements in a set of char to determine if they are all unique. ;)

Comment: @Tony D & other.And yes, there is probably a 32 Bit system out there with CHAR_BIT > 8 that can address more then 2^32 Bytes of memory that my statement didn't account for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If that's the case, how could I reliably get the total number of elements between two iterators, when the amount of elements exceeds the signed maximum?

If you're dealing with that many elements, do you really want to be copying it into a set everytime you call the function?

I would either pass your container as a reference and either substitute in for your original method:

```
template<class Container>
bool all_elements_unique(Container& c) {
  std::set<typename Container::value_type> s(std::begin(c), std::end(c));
  return s.size() == c.size();
}
```

Or do a sort and `adjacent_find`:

```
template<class Container>
bool all_elements_unique(Container& c) {
  std::sort(c.begin(), c.end());
  return std::adjacent_find(c.begin(), c.end()) == c.end();
}
```